# A way to use iPad as a drawing tablet for Photoshop & Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, windows, ipad

Are there and apps/programs that allow an iPad to be used as a drawing tablet? I've tried Duet Display and Chrome Remote Desktop, which are great apps, but are not helpful with my situation. They don't allow you to click and drag with a stylus, pen, or finger - you can only click. I have a good drawing app on my iPad but it has limitations and my software is just sitting on my desktop unused. I do not like the Adobe apps available and I don't have a CC subscription anyways.

Comment: @JohnManly and Lightfulfoxtrot. Play nice, both of you.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [astropad](http://astropad.com/), which does basically what you say. It's worked well for me. It is mac only, though.

Comment: Well that's not super helpful for Windows. Thanks, though.

Comment: @LightfulFoxtrot I edited your post, to specify Windows-only.  Next time,  add the tag when you originally post and you won't have to come back and clarify.