# How can I best make iPad mini + PC = graphic pen tablet?

Tags: vector, drawing, drawing-tablet, ipad

I have an iPad mini.  My home and work laptops are Windows, and my phone is Android.

I would like to use the iPad in a way as close to a monitor graphics tablet - like Cintiq - as possible.  I already own the iPad and can't afford another tablet.

First, the current favored program seems to be AstroPad, but it's Mac only.  Is there an equivalent quality Windows app?
- I have read scattered comments that some programs have had a history of complaints of lag between input and display, or jerky motion, which I hope to minimize.

Secondly, what styli are most commonly used by artists?
Which have the least lag from pen stroke to visualization of stroke?
- I have seen complaints of lag on reviews of some styli, but others are without comment.  I do not know what styli are most commonly used by actual artists, beginners or otherwise.

Comment: As far as the stylus goes, I think this is more of a product comparison thing. Information about stylus comparison can be found all over the web and is quite opinion based as well.

Comment: related: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/70221/a-way-to-use-ipad-as-a-drawing-tablet-for-photoshop-illustrator

Answer (score 0):

I always used a program called Splashtop to achieve the same. It works, but there is a little lag. There isn't a jerk, but it takes a momement to train your hand to accept the lag, but there's no way to get rid of it logically, outside of buying an actual graphics tablet.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself, but there seems to be a cross-platform app to mirror your desktop into ipad, much like astropad:
https://www.duetdisplay.com/